# Parsing String into date using java

Tags: java

I am trying to parse string into a date using the following code:

```
public static Date dateFormatter(String s)
{
    SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("MMddYYYY"); 
    Date excelDate=null;
    try
    {
        excelDate = ft.parse(s);    
        Date formatString = ft.format(excelDate);
        System.out.println("Date to be printed in Excel is :" +formatString);
        return excelDate;
    }
    catch(Exception ae)
    {
        System.out.println("No date");
    }
    return excelDate;
}
```

I am passing in the argument `"04202017"`.

This function is not working for me. I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong. Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Try `"MMddyyyy"` .

Comment: [`format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date)) is not [`parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String))

Comment: Why do you format the parse result ? (into the wrong type)

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `ft.parse(s);` instead of `format(excelDate)`. Format is the other way (`Date -> String`)

[DateFormat.parse(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String))

And you dont have to parse the `Date` back to a `String`.

Corrected code:

```
public static Date dateFormatter(String s) {
    SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("MMddYYYY"); 
    Date excelDate = null;
    try {
        excelDate = ft.parse(s);    
        System.out.println("Date to be printed in Excel is :" +excelDate);
        return excelDate;
    } catch(Exception ae) {
        System.out.println("No date");
    }
    return excelDate;
}
```

Comment: YYYY is not a valid decleration for year i think. It should be MMddyyyy or something like that.

Comment: OP is already doing that, but he is trying to reformat the `excelDate `, into a Date ( instead of a String). So this answer is not correct (yet ;) ) PS : _You have to use `ft.parse(excelDate); `_, you means `parse(s)` ? Because you can't pass a Date into `parse`

Comment: @AxelH I corrected my answer

Comment: Yeah i am trying to reformat the the string 04202017 into 2017-04-20.. I was trying to write a function which takes string as as an argument and returns date in format of YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 1):

Try [parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-) method instead of [format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format-java.util.Date-)

For String to Date, use:

```
SimpleDateFormat.parse(String);
```

For Date to String, use:

```
SimpleDateFormat.format(date);
```

However, in your code, you already parsed the String and assigned into `excelDate` on this line:

```
excelDate = ft.parse(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to use Java 1.8's new time classes (which are in java.time.* package).

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{        
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    // To String
    String dateString = dateTime.format(formatter);
    System.out.println(dateString);

    // To LocalDateTime
    LocalDateTime parsedLocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter);
}
```

Comment: This is only formatting the current date, you should include the way to parse a String into a `LocalDateTime` in your answer to be correct. Since this is the opposite ;)

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right. I've edited it.

Answer (score 1):

You already parsed String s to excelDate with date format that you want. So i think it's good and enough to print just excelDate.

```
System.out.println("Date to be printed in Excel is :" +excelDate);
```

Like that.

And also change `MMddYYYY` to `MMddyyyy`.

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
    String string = "march 9, 2017";
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date date = format.parse(string);
    System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: Why did you changed the format ? But correct

Comment: i just give the example how to convert string format to date,THANKS FOR YOUR FEEDBACK @AxelH

Comment: I agree, but since there is a mistake in his pattern, he might be difficult to understand your answer since it use a more complex one (the `MMMM` part).

Comment: I want in the format of  YYYY-MM-DD @Anantham .. Thanks for your guidance :)